# Apple Maps: Why does hybrid type appear odd in the Simulator for Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, apple-maps

I'm encountering a problem with hybrid-type Apple maps on the Xcode simulator after I upgraded to Xcode 7.  I've got a workaround, but I'm at a loss to explain why there is a problem or why my workaround works.

I've got a map view inside a UIView that is embedded in a Navigation Controller. I have buttons in the toolbar to do various things, among them being the ability to switch between the three main types of Apple maps.

When I'm fully zoomed out on a world view, the standard and satellite types display perfectly. When I switch to hybrid, however, I get an almost-there map, with all the names and with a hint of reddish lines denoting coastlines and nation borders, but all with a dark-gray background (image to be added as soon as I figure out how to do it). It doesn't seem to be a matter of a loading delay because the display stays incomplete no matter how long I leave it up.

My workaround is that if I tap to zoom in, the hybrid map then appears perfectly. I adapted that tap to work programmatically by using didUpdateUserLocation to zoom in on userLocation.

At first, I thought if might be a conflict between the image size and the container, but all three types are all the same size. I've looked at the subviews of the three types and they're identical to each other. I've added code to set values for the showsTraffic, showsScale and showsCompass properties of the map view just to see if adding another level to the details might make the hybrid type behave -- but no, it still appears odd. I even tried sizeToFit on the map view -- nothing.

At first, I thought it might be my app, but then I tried the built-in Maps app in the Simulator and got the same problem. As soon as you zoom in, the hybrid type displays perfectly.

The app and hybrid maps behaved perfectly fine in Xcode 6 -- the problem came when I upgraded to Xcode 7. At first, I compiled for iOS 9, but also tried iOS 8 and iOS 7 -- the problem was still there.

The View Controllers and their views are fully defined in a storyboard.  Here's my h file:

```
@interface ViewController :    UIViewController<UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
  IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;

  IBOutlet UIView *allOfTheView;

  IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

  IBOutlet UINavigationItem *mainMap;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *select;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *type;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *add;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *del;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *buy;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *instructions;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *share;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *mainMap;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *allOfTheView;

@end
```

Here's the viewDidLoad in my m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];

  [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

  [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

  [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

  self.myMapView.delegate = self;

  [self.myMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

  geocodeComplete = NO;

  [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
  self.activityIndicator.hidden = TRUE;

  pinDropAllowed = NO;
}
```

Here's the viewWillAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated];

  self.myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
  self.myMapView.showsCompass = YES;
  self.myMapView.showsScale = YES;
  self.myMapView.showsTraffic = YES;
  self.myMapView.showsPointsOfInterest = NO;
  self.myMapView.showsBuildings = NO;  
}
```

Here's the viewDidAppear:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];

   NSLog(@"MAP: viewDidAppear");

  self.mainMap.title = @"Year and Place";

  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressOnMap:)];

  lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;  //user must hold for 1 second

  [self.myMapView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

  lpgr.delegate = self;

  latArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  longArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  pinColorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  [self.myMapView reloadInputViews];
}
```

Here's the code for pressing the Type button in the Toolbar:

```
- (IBAction)typePressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
  if (self.myMapView.mapType == MKMapTypeStandard)
  {
    self.myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    NSLog(@"For satellite");
  }
else
{
    if (self.myMapView.mapType == MKMapTypeSatellite)
    {
        self.myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
        NSLog(@"For hybrid");
    }
    else
    if ( self.myMapView.mapType == MKMapTypeHybrid)
        {
            self.myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            NSLog(@"For standard");
        }
}

int holdHeight = self.myMapView.viewForFirstBaselineLayout.bounds.size.height;
int holdWidth = self.myMapView.viewForFirstBaselineLayout.bounds.size.width;

NSLog(@"Height is %d and width is %d", holdHeight, holdWidth);
}
```

If there's anything else you'd like to see, let me know. To sum up, what is different about the hybrid type of Apple map from the other two types that would cause it to appear differently?

And, no, I'm not at a point where I can try this on an actual device yet.

ETA:
[image: Misbehaving hybrid map]

Comment: And no sooner do I post this than I go try the built-in Map app on the Xcode 7 Simulator and now there's no problem at all.  The app still misbehaves though.